# No froms errors are getting printed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 forms in page which are as below and even i include the error printing sections those are not getting printed

```
<code>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <% if @user.personal %>
    <h2>Personal Details</h2>
    <div class="image"><%= image_tag (@user.personal.avatar_url(:thumb))if @user.personal.avatar? %></div>
    <b>First Name</b>:  <%= @user.personal.first_name %><br>
    <b>Middle Name</b>:  <%= @user.personal.middle_name %><br>
    <b>Last Name</b>:  <%= @user.personal.last_name %><br>
    <b>Date of Birth</b> <%= @user.personal.date_of_birth %><br>
    <b>Gender</b>:  <%= @user.personal.gender %><br>
    <b>Category</b> <%= Category.find(@user.personal.category_id).category %><br>
    <b>Blood Group</b>:  <%= @user.personal.blood_group %><br>
    <b>Fathers_name</b>:  <%= @user.personal.fathers_name %><br>
    <b>Mothers_name</b>:  <%= @user.personal.mothers_name %><br>
    <% else %>
      <%= form_for([@user, Personal.new]) do |f| %>
        <% if @user.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this candidate from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
            <% @user.personal.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
         <p>
              <%= f.label :first_name  %><br/>
              <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
      </p>
        <p>
              <%= f.label :middle_name  %><br/>
              <%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
      </p>
        <p>
              <%= f.label :last_name  %><br/>
              <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
      </p>
      <p>
              <%= f.label :date_of_birth, "Date of Birth" %><br/>
              <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, start_year: 1985, end_year: 1999  %>
      </p>
      <p>
              <%= f.label :gender %><br/>
              <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(%w[M F O]) %>
      </p>
      <p>
              <%= f.label :blood_group %><br/>
              <%= f.select :blood_group, options_for_select(%w[AB A+ B+ O ]) %>
      </p>
      <p>
              <%= f.label :fathers_name %><br/>
              <%= f.text_field :fathers_name %>
      </p>
      <p>
              <%= f.label :mothers_name  %><br/>
              <%= f.text_field :mothers_name %>
      </p>
      <p>
              <%= f.label :category_id %></br>
              <%= select("personal", "category_id", Category.all.collect {|c| [c.category, c.id]}) %>
      </p>

      <p>
              <%= f.label :avatar %>
              <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
      </p>
      <p><%= f.submit "Submit", data: {confirm: "Are you sure information once submitted cant be modified ?"} %></p>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</code>
```

This is the first form this is getting in

```
app/views/user_dashboard/home.html.erb
```

I cant figure this out why the errors are not getting printed on failing the validations
present in personal.rb

```
class Personal < ActiveRecord::Base
  # every personal information belongs to a particular user
  belongs_to :user
  # carrierwave uploader
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  # validations
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 24}
  validates :middle_name, length: { maximum: 24}
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 24}
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1}
  validates :category_id, presence: true
  validates :blood_group, presence: true, length: { maximum: 2}
  validates :fathers_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 24}
  validates :mothers_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 24}
  validates :avatar, presence: true
  end
```

here is the `personals_controller.rb`

```
class PersonalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_personal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # This helps to create personals
  def create
   @user = current_user
   @personal = @user.create_personal(personal_params)
   redirect_to home_path
  end


  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def personal_params
      params.require(:personal).permit(:user_id, :category_id, :avatar, :date_of_birth, :gender, :blood_group, :fathers_name, :mothers_name, :address_present, :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name)
    end
end
```

and here are some logs

```
Started POST "/users/36/personals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-11 23:57:20 +0530
Started POST "/users/36/personals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-11 23:57:20 +0530
Processing by PersonalsController#create as HTML
Processing by PersonalsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8qku1i/aIlz1aBdypnARzpiKuChWupPCMesjGoNmaTY=", "personal"=>{"first_name"=>"", "middle_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"1985", "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"7", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"11", "gender"=>"M", "blood_group"=>"AB", "fathers_name"=>"", "mothers_name"=>"", "category_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "user_id"=>"36"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8qku1i/aIlz1aBdypnARzpiKuChWupPCMesjGoNmaTY=", "personal"=>{"first_name"=>"", "middle_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"1985", "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"7", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"11", "gender"=>"M", "blood_group"=>"AB", "fathers_name"=>"", "mothers_name"=>"", "category_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "user_id"=>"36"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 36  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 36  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Personal Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `personals`.* FROM `personals`  WHERE `personals`.`user_id` = 36 LIMIT 1
  Personal Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `personals`.* FROM `personals`  WHERE `personals`.`user_id` = 36 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/home
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/home
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)




Started GET "/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-11 23:57:20 +0530
Started GET "/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-11 23:57:20 +0530
Processing by UserDashboardController#home as HTML
Processing by UserDashboardController#home as HTML
```

routes.rb

```
# http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-nested-routes-with-Devise
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, :path => 'accounts'
  # users has personal academics and applications hence nested routes
  resources :users do
    resources :personals
    resources :academics
    resources :applications
  end

  # user_dashboard controller
  post 'user_dashboard/personal_creator'
  # Controlpanel route
  get 'controlpanels/controlpanel'
  get 'controlpanels/resetranks'
  get 'controlpanels/generateranks'
  # verify routes
  get 'vusers/verify'
  # dashboard url shortening
  match '/home',  to: 'user_dashboard#home', via: 'get'
  match '/controlpanel',  to: 'controlpanels#controlpanel', via: 'get'
  match '/verify', to: 'vusers#verify', via: 'get'
  # routes for streams
  resources :streams
  # routes for categories
  resources :categories
  # routes for cutoffs
  resources :cutoffs
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a more cleaner way to do this. In your controller method(assuming it's home) you can do:

```
def home
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) #your logic to find user
  @personal = @user.build_personal #assuming you have user has_one personal association
end
```

and then in your form

```
<%= form_for([@user, @personal]) do |f| %>
    <% if @personal.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@personal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this candidate from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @personal.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

In your create action(assuming this form takes to create action) you need to have something like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # logic to find user
  @personal = @user.build_personal(personal_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @personal.save
      format.html { redirect_to @personal }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "home" }
    end
  end
end

private
def personal_params
  params.require(:personal).permit(:your_attributes)
end
```

**Update:**

*If your form passes validations create_personal will simply create your record and in your case since it doesn't it will simply go to the step below it which is to redirect to home_path and hence no errors*

You can even see it in your logs

```
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 36  ORDER BY     `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Personal Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `personals`.* FROM `personals`  WHERE  `personals`.`user_id` = 36 LIMIT 1
Personal Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `personals`.* FROM `personals`  WHERE `personals`.`user_id` = 36 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/home
```

Comment: This didnt solve my problem it doesnot still show any error but thanks for refactoring  my code

Comment: @SouravMoitra can you show your logs and your controller method for creating personal?

Comment: @SouravMoitra you need to use build_personal and then check if it's saving it in database or not, if not render your new action(form) which will then display errors

Comment: how do i render new action(form) ??

Comment: @SouravMoitra Where do you have your form, i mean in which view, is it in home? updated it for home. You just need to `render your action which has form`

Comment: It is different controller user_dashboard_controller then home

Comment: @SouravMoitra what do you mean by different controller? Is it in different controller then the one in which you have your create method? If it's then instead of render action you can simply do **render your_form_path**

Comment: i have user_dashboard controller which has form and personal_controller which has create method

Comment: @SouravMoitra can you post your rake routes? You just need to use render your_method_path

Comment: I have added one more route
post 'user_dashboard/create_personal'

Comment: @SouravMoitra can you post rake routes in your question?

Comment: @SouravMoitra in which method you have your form? and what is this line doing `post 'user_dashboard/personal_creator'` you havent specified any controller and method for this

Answer (score 0):

```
class PersonalsController < ApplicationController

def create
     @user = current_user
     @personal = @user.build_personal(personal_params)
     if @personal.save
       flash[:notice] = "success"
     else
       flash[:alert] = @personal.errors.full_messages.each{|e|}
     end
     redirect_to home_path

  end

end
```

Is this is the answer?